# MySQL: Sum of first n and last n records of single column based on conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Is it possible to calculate sum of first 5 overs and last 5 overs from a single column? I am in a situation where I have to calculate it using query.

I have to calculate sum of first 5 overs and show it in different column, and similarly I have to calculate sum of last 5 overs and show it in another column. My table look like this:

```
Overs runs players

1   1     p1           
1   1     p2
1   4     p2
1   1     p2
1   0     p1
1   0     p1
2   1     p2
2   2     p1
2   3     p1
2   1     p2
```

Now it should calculate first five overs sum and calculate last five overs sum for each player and tell me which players scored how much runs in first 5 overs and how much they scored in last 5 overs.

```
players first5overSum last5overSum

 p1        40               0
 p2        50             120
 p3        10              60
```

MySQL query look like this:

```
SELECT player_key, 
    sum(runs) as first5overSum
FROM `batsman_scores`
WHERE over<=5 
group by player_key
```

I am able to calculate records for first 5 overs, but I don't know how to show last 5 overs sum of each player together and show it.

Please give me suggestions or solutions. I will be very thankful!

Comment: What do you mean by "first five"?

Comment: it means first five overs

Comment: According your data p1 has 2 overs (overs = 1,2) so how do you get first and last five for p1?.

Comment: Way to offer clarification and ensure you get people to help you! LOL! The terms "first" and "last" imply a sort order -- you might want to retry answering a legit question by explaining what you mean and how the first 5 and last 5 are determined.

Comment: ok Sloan Thrasher. But then i also explained what does my question means and i got right answer from Gordon Linoff.

Comment: You want upvotes? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: And there is no 'first' and 'last' here

Comment: Strawberry: we have 2 calculate first 5 overs records and last 5 records.... so here is 'first' and 'last' ..hmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use conditional aggregation.  I'm not quite sure what "first five" and "last five" mean, but the query would look something like this:

```
SELECT bs.player_key, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN bs.over <= 5 THEN bs.runs ELSE 0 END) as first5overSum,
       SUM(CASE WHEN bs.over > bs2.max_over - 5 THEN bs.runs ELSE 0 END) as last5overSum,
FROM batsman_scores bs CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT MAX(bs2.over) as max_over
      FROM batsman_scores bs2
     ) bs2
WHERE bs.over <= 5 
GROUP BY bs.player_key
```

Comment: first 5 means => first 5 overs and last 5 overs